# Issue connecting MySQL database to Java Spring Boot app Docker container

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, hibernate

I'm developing a person project that consists of a Spring Boot application.

I'm currently trying to create a Docker container for my app, but I'm having issues connecting the database to the app. I'm using docker-compose to join the app and the database in a single container.

**Firstly I'll provide the file structure of my project:

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzD5h.png)**

**Here is the Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:20-jdk

# Copy wait-for-it.sh script
COPY wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh

# Run the wait-for-it.sh script to wait for the database to be ready
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-it.sh

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Spring application JAR file into the container
COPY target/artifacts/hotelAPI_jar/hotelAPI.jar .

# Expose the port the Spring application listens on
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run Spring Boot application
CMD ["java", "-jar", "hotelAPI.jar"]
```

**Here is the docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: MYSQL_DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: hotel-MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: MYSQL_PASSWORD
    networks:
      - network

  hotel-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - network
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
    command: >
      sh -c '/wait-for-it.sh -t 60 mysql-db:3306 -- java -jar hotelAPI.jar'

networks:
  network:
```

I have removed all non essential information (the username, passwords and everything like  that is ok)

**Here are the dependencies on my pom.xml file:**

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Here is the application.properties file:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Again, I removed non essential information

**I'm running this command to run docker:**

```
docker-compose up
```

**I believe this isn't a problem, but it appears on the logs:**

```
2023-09-28 01:34:07 hotelapi-mysql-db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-09-28 01:34:07 hotelapi-mysql-db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-09-28 01:34:07 hotelapi-mysql-db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-09-28 01:34:08 hotelapi-mysql-db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-09-28 01:34:08 hotelapi-mysql-db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2023-09-28 01:34:08 hotelapi-mysql-db-1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
```

This appears before the app starts and it seams like mysql starts with no issues.

**Than the app starts and finally, here is the error:**

```
2023-09-28 01:34:17 hotelapi-hotel-app-1  | 2023-09-28T00:34:17.483Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2023-09-28 01:34:17 hotelapi-hotel-app-1  |
2023-09-28 01:34:17 hotelapi-hotel-app-1  | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2023-09-28 01:34:17 hotelapi-hotel-app-1  |
2023-09-28 01:34:17 hotelapi-hotel-app-1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

As you can imagine, the stack trace is huge. I don't know if I should include anything else.

I've tried to:

- Include the wait-for-it.sh to try to prevent the app from starting before the port 3306 is ready.
- Change the database url on the application.properties. Instead of using localhost I used mysql-db (the service name on the docker-compose.yml file).
- Change the versions of both the mysql driver dependency (on the pom.xml file) and the mysql docker image I'm using. I think it solved some problems I was having, but it still doesn't work.

I have been stuck on this problem for a very long time, so I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

My guess is that the problem is on the docker-compose.yml file, but I don't know.

Thanks for spending the time read this!

Comment: Wrong JDBC url. You need to use the service name (like you did in your command elemnet and not `localhost`).

Comment: So in this case it should be "mysql-db"?
If yes, I already tried it and it didn't work.
(they are in the same network, so the localhost works)

Comment: afaik localhost won't work as that will only resolve into the local container not the network and you have to use the service name. Instead of the script you use I suggest to use the `DatabaseStartupValidator` (See https://deinum.biz/2020-06-30-Wait-for-database-startup/). It looks like the connection can be made but there is no communication (I would expect a different exception if it wouldn't be reachable).

Comment: I've tried using the service name...and it didn't work...
About the DatabaseStartupValidator, I'm using wait-for-it, which waits until the port I give (3306 in this case) is on, so it should have the same effect...? I think.

Answer (score -1):

In your `docker-compose` MySQL section. Try to add :

```
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Complete file would be :

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: MYSQL_DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: hotel-MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: MYSQL_PASSWORD
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - network

  hotel-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - network
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
    command: >
      sh -c '/wait-for-it.sh -t 60 mysql-db:3306 -- java -jar hotelAPI.jar'

networks:
  network:
```

Also make sure `network` is properly defined as descried in [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Comment: `expose:` does nothing and it can be safely deleted.  `ports:` aren't used for connections between containers.  Compose provides a network named `default` automatically and things will work correctly if there are no `networks:` blocks at all in the file (also described in _Networking in Compose_, your final link).

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. :(
Thanks anyway.